# How can I make my pie chart only display unique strings and add the values from duplicated strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I am doing a web app using react and nodeJS and I am trying to get my pie chart to only display unique values and add the repeated string values so it looks nice and clean
Right now this is what is showing.

**(Pie chart and array on picture)** https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvrXk.png This is a dynamic array that am i fetching the info from an api and saving it into a 2d array

**This is the code am using to populate the array (Last for loop)**

```
const getTransactions = async (accountId) => {
    setIncome(0);
    setExpenses(0);
    await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/plaid/transactions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_id: accountId,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setTransactions(response.transactions);
        response.transactions.forEach((transaction) => {
          if (transaction.amount > 0) {
            setIncome((prevState) => prevState + transaction.amount);
          } else {
            setExpenses((prevState) => prevState - transaction.amount);
          }
        });

        tempPieData.push(["Names", "Amounts"]);

        for (let dataObj of response.transactions) {
          tempPieData.push([dataObj.category[0], Math.abs(dataObj.amount)]);
        }

        console.log(tempPieData);

        setPieData(tempPieData);
      });
  };
```

**This is how am loading the pie chart using react google charts**

```
const options = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    is3D: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
  };
 {selectedAccount !== null && (
          <div className="pieChart">
            <Chart chartType="PieChart" data={PieData} options={options} />
          </div>
```

Any help or Ideas on how I can make this only show "Travel" and "Food and Drinks" on the legend and the combination of values of the repeated strings in the array. No hard code please I am looking for dynamic since I cant know what category of transactions the user is going to make.